# How to loop through a list of tuples using a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tuples

I have a list that contains lists of tuples. Here is a sample of the data.

```
[ 144.91, 145.03, 145.1] [ 12964.0, 12818.0, 13441.0] [123.23, 152.45, 132.75] [12523.51, 12425.32, 12225.1] [122.22, 123.42, 120.21] [12444.43, 12232.22, 12111.12]
```

The list is structured as x and y pairs. For example, [ 144.91, 145.03, 145.1] is x1 and [ 12964.0, 12818.0, 13441.0] is y1. Then the sequence repeats, [123.23, 152.45, 132.75] is x2 and [12523.51, 12425.32, 12225.1] is y2.....

What i am trying to do is pass the x and y pairs into a for loop that inserts each x and y individual tuples into its own column within a common row inside SQL. However this is where my problem occurs.

if i use the below loop code i can insert the entire x tuple and y tuple into a single row but it will repeat the same x tuple and y tuple in ever row without iterating through.

```
for i in range(len(hex_strings_list)):
    insert_query(x_tuple_values,y_tuple_values)
```

if i attempt to iterate through each list of tuples with this code the for loop will insert each number within each tuple within its own row.

```
for i in range(len(hex_strings_list)):
    print(x_tuple_values[i],y_tuple_values[i])
```

i know that i want to iterate through the tuples rather than the individual numbers that make up the tuple, but i'm at a loss how to accomplish this. total mental block!

Comment: I don't know if I understood well you question.

Let me try:

your values are organized like this: `values=[x1, y1, ..... xn, yn]` and you need call insert_query(x1, y1), insert_query(x2, y2) etc

a loop like this should work
`[insert_query(values[a], values[a+1]) for a in range(0,len(values),2)]`

Comment: your assumption about the data format is correct. However the for loop looks strange since you have the query outside of the for loop. Or was that more pseudo code? And fyi this is python 3.

Comment: yes, I used list comprehension format to be more compact, but sure you will not use this way unless you need the results of insert_query in a list. 
`for a in range(0,len(values),2): 

        insert_query(values[a], values[a+1])`